# Toggle bash script between run commands and print commands

Tags: bash, debugging

I found a script which used this "trick" to achieve a toggle between running and printing commands:

```
echo_prefix="echo"
rm_cmd="rm file1 file2"
$echo_prefix $rm_cmd
```

This allows the user to dry run the script and then set `echo_prefix=""`
to effectively run the script.

Still, I found many problems related to globbing and quoting so I was looking for a different and more robust approach.

Comment: Mm, what are the problems with globbing and quoting? Do you want to see e.g. globs and variables expanded in the output? (that's what the `echo` would do.)

Comment: Related to that, what should the "dry-run" mode do with command substitutions? They're commands in itself and might have effects, but they also affect the main command line, so should they be executed?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for this is using `| bash`.

So basically, you just echo your command. Here in my example `rm file1 file2` and then `| bash` will run the output.

```
[ws] user ~ >echo "rm file1 file2"
rm file1 file2
[ws] user ~ >echo "rm file1 file2" | bash
rm: cannot remove ‘file1’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘file2’: No such file or directory
```

---

@Kusalananda, If you have space in file name, you just have to adapt the first part to keep the quotes in the echo command:

```
echo "rm \"file with space\"" | bash
```

Comment: Try that with `rm "file with space in name"`...

Comment: You just have to adapt the first part: echo "rm \"file with space\"" | bash